# Does $0<x_1<x_2<1$ imply $x_1<1$?

Tags: inequality, probability-distributions

I have a PDF $$
f_{X_1,X_2}(x,y)
$$
with the support$$
S=\{(x_1,x_2):0<x_1<x_2<1\}
$$

When finding $f_{X_1}$, the solution had the integral:

$$
f_{X_1}(x_1)=\int^{1}_{x_2}f_{X_1,X_2}(x,y)dx_2
$$
for $0<x_1<1$

---

My question is, why is the support of $f_{X_1}$ given by $T=\{x_1:0<x_1<1\}$ ?

The support $S$ states that $x_1<x_2<1$ which I think should not imply $x_1<1$, **unless $S=\{(x_1,x_2):0<x_1<x_2≤1\}$**.

I think support $T$ should have the bound $0<x_1<x_2$ instead of $0<x_1<1$

Furthermore,

$$
f_{X_2}(x_2)=\int^{x_2}_{1}f_{X_1,X_2}(x,y)dx_1
$$
for $0<x_2<1$

Which again should have the support $x_1<x_2<1$

Comment: I don't understand, if $x_1<1$ that always means that there is a $x_2$ strictly between $x_1$ and $1$

Comment: Answer to the question in the title is obviously yes, since inequality is transitive. Though it's not clear if the body of the post asks the same question.

Comment: Let $r\in(0,1)$. Is it possible that $X_1$ takes value $r$ as value? Yes, because we could have $X_1=r<X_2<1$. This shows that *every* $r\in(0,1)$ is in the support of $X_1$.

Comment: @drhab That is not explicitly stated in the given. All I know is that $X_1$ and $X_2$ have the joint PDF for $0<x_1<x_2<1$

Comment: Following @drhab comment, I think that it is implicitly assumed by the problem. I'll go with that, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convenience let us write $X$ for $X_1$ and $Y$ for $X_2$. Then $(X,Y)$ has a PDF $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ and formally that is a function on $\mathbb R^2$. It is evident though that it will take only positive values on $(0,1)^2$ so again for convenience let us think of it as a function on $\Bbb (0,1)^2$.

Since $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ takes value $0$ if $x<y$ is not true we can write:$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_{X,Y}(x,y)[x<y]$$
where $[x<y]$ is a function on $(0,1)^2$ that takes value $1$ if $x<y$ is satisfied and takes value $0$ otherwise.

Then for $x\in(0,1)$ we find: $$f_X(x)=\int_0^1 f_{X,Y}(x,y)[x<y]dy=\int_x^1f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy$$This because the integrand takes value $0$ on interval $(0,x]$.

It might well be that for every $x\in(0,1)$ this gives a positive value $f_X(x)$ and this on its own is enough to state that the support of $X$ is $(0,1)$.